# Advancing the "cursor" in an associative array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array like such:

```
$arr = array('format' => 'A4', 'coulor' => 'red', 'height' = > '30');
```

I would like to use it in an mysql query like such:

```
reset($arr);

$first_key = key($arr); // get the first key of the array

$sql = "// sql query here...";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

   echo $row[$first_key]; // will echo out the content of a table field
}
```

How to advance the cursor of this associative array so I can echo out the content of the next column in the mysql table

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use the keys of your `$arr` then just do:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   foreach($arr as $key=>$v)
      echo $row[$key];
}
```

Otherwise you can simply use `mysqli_fetch_row()` In this way your keys are integers, and you can get the next by doing:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

  echo $row[0]; // will echo out the content of a table field
  echo $row[1]; // will echo out the content of a table field

}
```